# Symbol not found error

Tags: java

I am doing a project for school. In that project there were various classes given to me, with the task to complete them.

One of my classes `Orbita`, creates an object from another `Graficos`. `Graficos` was given to me completed but as `bytecode`, not as source.

When I try to compile it, it gives me the following error

> the symbol not found error every time `Orbita` uses the class
>   `Graficos`.

It gives my an error on every time it has `Graficos. (..)`

```
C:\Users\user1\Desktop\loll\trabalho (1)>javac -cp ptplot5.8:. *.java
Orbita.java:206: error: cannot find symbol
Graficos.mostraGrafico(vectorParaGrafico, legendas);
^
symbol:   variable Graficos
location: class Orbita
Orbita.java:230: error: cannot find symbol
Graficos.mostraGrafico(vectorParaGrafico,
^
symbol:   variable Graficos
location: class Orbita
Orbita.java:262: error: cannot find symbol
Graficos.mostraGrafico(vectorParaGrafico, legendas);
^
symbol:   variable Graficos
location: class Orbita
Orbita.java:283: error: cannot find symbol
Graficos.mostraGrafico(vectorParaGrafico,
^
symbol:   variable Graficos
location: class Orbita
4 errors

C:\Users\user1\Desktop\loll\trabalho (1)>
```

My code:

```
 public void projecta2D(int coordX, int coordY) {
    double[][] vectorParaGrafico = new double[iteracoes + 1][2];
    for (int k = 0; k <= iteracoes; k++) {
      vectorParaGrafico[k][0] = registo[k].getCoordenada(coordX);
      vectorParaGrafico[k][1] = registo[k].getCoordenada(coordY);
    }

    Graficos.mostraGrafico(vectorParaGrafico,
                   new String[]{"coordenada 1", "coordenada 2", "orbita"});
 }

 public void serieTemporal(int coordenada, int inicio, int fim,
                           String[] legendas) {

  if (inicio < 0)
    inicio = 0;
  if (fim > iteracoes)
    fim = iteracoes;

  double[][] vectorParaGrafico = new double[fim - inicio + 1][2];
  for (int k = inicio; k <= fim; k++) {
    vectorParaGrafico[k][0] = k;
    vectorParaGrafico[k][1] = registo[k].getCoordenada(coordenada);
  }

  Graficos.mostraGrafico(vectorParaGrafico, legendas);
}
```

Comment: Please, could you attach the error output?

Comment: How are you running the program? What's your directory structure and are you using `java -cp`? What `package` is each class in? Your code doesn't matter, the questions I'm asking are the ones that matter, please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Prima facie, it seems you need to Import the class Graficos..

Comment: How do you import ""Graficos" ?

Comment: im compiling it in command prompt, and yes i am using java -cp, my directory has all the classes including the class. file Graficos

Comment: You need to know package declaration of the class Graphicos. Then you can import it using `import something.something.Graficos;` Or if you are using Eclipse IDE press ctrl+shift+o, it will import the class if it is under classpath.

Comment: Hi @user3636673, your question misses a proper question and therefore needs a bit more clarification. Please edit your question and precise the sentence: It gives my an error on every time it has "Graficos. (..)"